# Global scope preventing DB seeding

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-spark

I am using Laravel spark, and I am restricting team access to models by employing a scope that is implemented in a trait

```
namespace App\Scopes;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Scope;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class TeamScope implements Scope
{
    /**
     * Apply the scope to a given Eloquent query builder.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $builder
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $model
     * @return void
     */
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        $builder->where('team_id', '=',Auth()->user()->currentTeam->id );
    }
}
```

my issue is that when I run the DB seeder it fails because there is no user to auth against.

The seeder doesn't have any methods to allow me to log in a particular user.

is there a way to disable the global scope whilst seeding, or any other solution for that matter?

THanks

Answer (score 2):

If you're calling the model inside the seed, you can just call `->withoutGlobalScopes()` first

more on that here https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#query-scopes at the 'Removing Global Scopes' section.